# h:inputText does not dynamically change the 'value' after onclick (IE)

Tags: javascript, richfaces

i'm trying to fill out a textfile to the h:inputText value after a fileupload. several hours and i have not been successful in providing a solution to this. Code works on FF36, Safari, GC.

```
<ui:composition>

    <h:outputLabel styleClass="tab-label" value="Data Filename to Upload : " />                 

    <h:inputText id="#{fileID.concat('FileName')}" type="text" class="form-text" value="#{searchesPageBean.searchBean.file.name}" readonly="true" /> 

    <input type="button" class="filter-btn browse-btn" value="Browse" 
        onclick="clickBrowse(#{'\''.concat(fileID).concat('\'')});" >
    </input>

    <div style="opacity: 0; height: 0px; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; z-index: " >
        <rich:fileUpload id="#{fileID.concat('FileUpload')}"  
            fileUploadListener="#{searchesPageBean.searchBean.listener}"
            maxFilesQuantity="#{searchesPageBean.searchBean.uploadsAvailable}"
            immediateUpload="#{searchesPageBean.searchBean.autoUpload}"
            acceptedTypes="txt"
            autoclear="true" 
            ajaxSingle="true">
            <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="#{fileID.concat('FileUpload,').concat(fileID.concat('FileName, ').concat(fileID.concat('ViewFileName,')))}"
                ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true" 
                action="#{searchesPageBean.searchBean.clearUploadData()}" />
        </rich:fileUpload>                  
    </div>

</ui:composition>
```

things i've tried so far:

- `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`
- remove `readonly=true`
- placed `onsubmit=true` on `<input type>`

really need this badly. thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging the JavaScript to see what's happening?

Comment: I don't get any errors on FF/Safari but on IE, i get:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method. 

This comes up when the text file upload stalls on IE10. I have though of patching richfaces as this could the a compatibility issue on IE but I am considering a lot of components on our project that could get affected if i do this. (http://ruleoftech.com/2013/patching-richfaces-3-3-3-ajax-js-for-ie9)

Comment: That gives you an answer, doesn't it? Or at least let's you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes, but patching richfaces would be risky. I guess I have to try converting codes from `rich:fileUpload` to `s:fileUpload`.

Comment: What I meant is that clearly this is a JavaScript problem, so you can change the question and show the JavaScript code where the problem happens, instead of JSF code that doesn't show anything.

Comment: Oh a sorry @Makhiel, I wasn't able to catch the javascript line when I encountered the problem in IE10 but I'm pretty sure there was "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method." -this happens while uploading the text file. I've read alot of issues of richfaces 3.3.3 on `rich:fileupload` using IE8/9 unfortunately, i've also experienced it on IE10 (we can't have Richfaces 4 upgrade due to some version-dependent codes could get affected) so I thought upgrading to IE11 would provide a solution at least on our side. -still persists and now debugging IE crashes on press of F12.

Comment: I've tried to re-create the issue on IE10 and this is what i got now on IE debug mode on javascript:

'SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
ui.pack.js, line 12635 character 1'

then i followed the line:
'this.scrollBox.element.scrollTop=C;'